# Installing rgdal - cannot solve dependencies

Tags: gdal, proj, rgdal, deployment

I am trying to build a docker image based on `osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-XXXXX`. However it keeps failing when trying to install `rgdal`. I've tried this on gdal-3.1.1/proj-7.1.0 and gdal-3.0.3/proj-6.3.0, as well as from `ubuntu-full-v2.5.0RC1`.

After some deep digging, it looks like the error stems from this:

```
configure:2847: g++ -std=gnu++11   -DPROJ_H_API -I/usr/local/include  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro conftest.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lproj    -L/usr/lib -lgdal >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lproj
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2851: $? = 1
configure:2889: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
```

resulting in a status that looks like this:

```
...
configure: rgdal: 1.5-12
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 1018
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 3.0.3
checking GDAL version >= 1.11.4... yes
checking GDAL version <= 2.5 or >= 3.0... yes
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: gdal-config data directory readable... yes
checking GDAL: /usr/share/gdal/stateplane.csv readable... yes
configure: pkg-config proj exists, will use it
configure: PROJ version: 6.3.0
configure: PROJ CPP flags: -DPROJ_H_API -I/usr/local/include
configure: PROJ LIBS: -L/usr/local/lib -lproj
checking PROJ header API:... yes
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpxFc0qV/R.INSTALL1e86d5b26dc/rgdal':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rgdal'
```

Some googling led me to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600978/cpp-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary).
I tried to munge things by `ln -sv /usr/local/lib/libproj.so.19 /usr/local/lib/libproj.so` but that just results in:

```
configure: error: proj_context_create not found in libproj.
```

I then tried some
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
autoconf
./configure

Still complaining of `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lproj` !

Here's a Dockerfile you can use to reproduce:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as base

# Setup tzdata and set timezone so we don't get prompted for it later
RUN     echo 'Etc/UTC' > /etc/timezone \
    &&  export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    &&  ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime \
    &&  apt-get update -qq \
    &&  apt-get install -q -y tzdata \
    &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    &&  dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

RUN     apt-get update -qq \
    &&  apt-get install -qq autoconf curl git build-essential dirmngr software-properties-common \
    &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN     apt-key adv --no-tty --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 \
    &&  add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/' \
    &&  apt-get update -qq \
    &&  apt-get install -y r-base \
    &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN echo 'install.packages("rgdal")' | R --no-save
```